# A software to read xml in command line interface

Tags: xml, command-line

I'm looking for a command line xml viewer under Linux.

What I'm seeking :

1. easy navigation for both classical page up/down as well as through the tree and attribute structures
2. ability to switch beetween a tree view/plain text view
3. syntax coloration
4. folding

What I don't care about:

1. xml edition

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207516/xml-editor-for-linux