# Text Editor to view AndroidManifest.xml on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, text-editor, xml

**Edit:**

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file in an APK package is not classic XML (text) but binary XML. This claim is backed by these sources: [Infosec](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-malware-analysis/), [Androguard](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/) and output of `file -i`:

```
AndroidManifest.xml: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

while a text editor usually requires:

```
AndroidManifest_new.xml: application/xml; charset=us-ascii
```

The conversion to classic XML can be achieved in Linux but it requires Java which as mentioned below I want to avoid.

---

**Earlier:**

I'm looking for a text editor that can **easily** enable me to view `AndroidManifest.xml` file (e.g. [1](http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/uJYni8ki/file.html),[2](http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/R4ihHPsX/file.html),[3](http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/bYjkJABD/file.html)) found in Android packages (APK).

### Requirements

- The software should support (preferred) **Slackware 14.1** (Primary OS; with KDE 4.10).

  Alternatively, it should support **Linux Mint 17** (based on Ubuntu 14.04; running KDE 4.13).
- A proof is required that the software can view the said XML file.
- **Strongly** prefers GUI over CLI(color coding preferred).
- Freeware is preferred but no bars on paid or proprietary ones.
- Shouldn't require WINE.
- Suggestions for browser extension/addons are also invited.
- Can be a plugin for a native Linux text editor like Kate, Kwrite, *et al*.
- Can be an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.xmleditor) which can export the said file into a file readable by any text editor. Note that formatting shouldn't be affected in this process (scroll below to know more).

### What have I tried so far?

Tried for multiple said XML files:

- I tried [XMLcopyeditor](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.1/development/xmlcopyeditor/?search=xmlcopy) (v1.2.1.2) on Slackware but it doesn't show human readable output for `AndroidManifest.xml`
- [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) and [SublimeText 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) also shows gibberish for the said XML file.
- I didn't try any CLI based viewers since I strongly want GUI.
- Firefox and Chromium throws error in opening said XML file.
- [Conglomerate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conglomerate/) isn't updated since 2013, and as obvious, didn't compile on Slackware because of requirements for age old libraries.
- I didn't try [KXML Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxmleditor/) since it's hasn't been updated since 2013.
- [XV — XML Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xv-%E2%80%94-xml-viewer/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk) has very bad reviews so trying it was out of the question for me.

<sub>(**Note** that if you're certain that your candidate would meet the aforesaid requirements than you may suggest the software irrespective of whether I tried it or not.)</sub>

### Search results I found?

Following are some questions on SE sites that I found but none worked for me:

- [A software to read xml in command line interface](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/a-software-to-read-xml-in-command-line-interface)
- [xml editor for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207516/xml-editor-for-linux)
- [XML editing in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429557/xml-editing-in-linux)
- [Decent KDE XML viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652429/decent-kde-xml-viewer)
- [Is there an XML file editor for Linux with grid view support?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/780/is-there-an-xml-file-editor-for-linux-with-grid-view-support)

### What else?

Their seems to be two strong candidates namely [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) and [jEdit](http://jedit.org/index.php?page=download).

- I didn't try former because it's a paid software and I'm not sure whether it would work on said XML file.
- I didn't install latter because it requires Java Runtime installed which is surely a mess from security perspective.

<sub>(Let me know if any of these two contenders can also work for the said XML file.)</sub>

### An indirect way?

Presently, I'm using an app named [Axel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.xmleditor) on Android which can save the said XML file as a `.txt` file. I then copy it from device into my system and uses Kate to see the file. However, it affects a lot of formatting which I want to avoid.

---

Thank you very much for any help you can offer!

Comment: if *Kate and SublimeText 2 also shows gibberish for the said XML file.*, doesn't it suggest the file might have issues? Did you try catting the file?

Comment: What encoding are those files? They don't seem to be anything my system recognises, and don't appear to be XML :/

Comment: @ElliotReed Check my edit, you'll see why your/my system doesn't recognize the said XML.

Comment: To Downvoters: Why a **downvote**? Please cite a reason in the comment. This question IMO shows research efforts, is clear and useful, not to mention I tried to follow quality question guideline of this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't install Java Runtime system-wide, but rather confined the [extracted content](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) into a directory `jre` under my Home directory,  downloaded [AXMLPrinter2.jar](https://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar&) ([suggested on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=514412)), and finally created an [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) for its usage in [`.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work).

My alias was simple:

```
AXML='~/Downloads/jre/bin/java -jar ~/Downloads/jre/AXMLPrinter2.jar'
```

and the usage of this alias on any given binary `AndroidManifest.xml` file anywhere in the system would be:

```
AXML <Binary_XML> > <New_XML>
```

E.g.:

```
AXML ~/AndroidManifest.xml > AndroidMF.xml
```

The `AndroidMF.xml` is now human-readable and can be opened by any XML supported text editor. You can also save the file into a `.txt` rather than a `.xml` file. Note that formatting is a lot better than the method I mentioned in my question.

Because Java Runtime is available for most of the Operating Systems there shouldn't be any reason why this (or most relevant parts) answer shouldn't work on your system (exception of alias).

Answer (score 0):

I'll jump in with **Geany** and the extension *XML PrettyPrinter*. I use Geany for pretty much everything, and the XML PrettyPrinter extension has always worked fine for me.

However, what you appear to be after is **not** an XML reader, rather a parser for the files as extracted from an APK.

APKTool is a good place to start: http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

The XML it (or any other tool) generates may not be spot-on, but will at least be more helpful than the raw file by a long way! As for a GUI tool, I'm afraid I am not sure on that one (but as it's a parser you're likely after, that shouldn't be too much of an issue I guess).

Comment: Thanks! Could you mention the hyperlink for this Geany extension? I would like to see how it would work on said XML file. As for APKTool it needs Java which means I'll only use it if I don't see any more recommendations.

Comment: I installed Geany with that extension/plugin but sadly Geany doesn't recognize the encoding. Any more recommendations?

Comment: It won't recognise the file unless it's parsed first - the XML from Android's packages isn't a "normal" XML file.

Comment: If you don't want to use Java, there are plenty of others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package Although JRE isn't really a security issue, and if you are concerned you could run it in a jail or sandbox (or something like Firejail: https://l3net.wordpress.com/projects/firejail/)